# Can I get vagrant to execute a series of commands where I get shell access and the webserver launches?

Tags: vagrant

Everytime I launch vagrant for one of our projects I go through the following incantation:

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
sudo su deploy
supervisorctl stop local
workon odoo-8.0
/home/deploy/odoo/build/8.0/openerp-server -c /home/deploy/odoo/local/odoo_serverrc
```

This runs the server in a way that lets me see the terminal output. Is there a way I could package this all up so I can do say; `vagrant dev` or some such?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell provisioner.

In your vagrantfile, you can do things like this:

```
$script = <<SCRIPT
echo I am provisioning...
date > /etc/vagrant_provisioned_at
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
end
```

You can replace

```
echo I am provisioning...
date > /etc/vagrant_provisioned_at
```

with your own commands.

On the first 'vagrant up' that creates the environment, provisioning is run. If the environment was already created and the up is just resuming a machine or booting it up, they won't run unless the --provision flag is explicitly provided.

There are many more good ways to provision, I would also recommend using Ansible. Here is the doc you can read:
https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html

Comment: I think I was a bit unclear. I have the machine already provisioned and running through ansible. This is something I want to do with an already running and installed machine.

Comment: OK, forget about the provision. I guess you could simply write a shell script named 'vagrant_dev' containing your commands. Then run the script like this "./vagrant_dev".  If the script failed to run because of permission, you could do this: chmod 755 vagrant_dev

Answer (score 0):

First, create a shell script with your commands in them:

```
#!/bin/bash
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
sudo su deploy
supervisorctl stop local
workon odoo-8.0
/home/deploy/odoo/build/8.0/openerp-server -c /home/deploy/odoo/local/odoo_serverrc
```

Put it somewhere in your guest with ansible. Next, copy the /home/vagrant/.bashrc file into yoour ansible files/ folder. Add the line

```
bash /path/to/shellfile.sh
```

to the .bashrc and make sure ansible copies it into your guest.

After that, the shell script should be executed every time you log into the guest.